# How to align MenuItem popup to the right bottom corner of the Menu

Tags: java, menuitem, javafx-8, menubar

Javafx standard MenuItem of the MenuBar displays like:

[image]

I would like it to display such that the menuitem is aligned with the right bottom corner of the menu:
[image]

I tried to modify the css properties of the MenuItem, but it only changed the text alignment of the menu, no impact on the position of the menuitem. Is there a simple way to do it with css properties?

Comment: curious: why do you want to change standard visuals?

Comment: As my menu bar is in the right corner of the window, with the standard visual, the menu item popup will display out of the window

Comment: can you paste a few lines of code of your html structure ?

Comment: right aligned menus aren't standard - so my curiousity still awake :-) BTW, for a left aligned menu item the popup displays outside the window for the right most menu as well (if the window is small enough/are enough menus in the bar), so arguably it might not be viewed as sooo wrong. Astonished though, that I couldn't find any configuration option as well.

Comment: I just had a similar use case (although not similar enough to make it an immediate answer). Effectively, I wanted the anchoring point of a node to be its top right corner instead of the top left, so I bound `layoutX` to `-width`. Maybe the same is applicable here?

Answer (score 2):

Do change the Orientation from Inherit to `RIGHT_TO_LEFT`
[image]